# billing agreement token lifetime

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

When I create an agreement for paypal payment, it return the REDIRECT link with a token.

The user must connect to paypal via this link and accept agreement, then I can execute agreement.

I want to know, how long the REDIRECT link (and its assoicated token) is valid ? I ask because I want top precompute agreement and put them in cache, so If user want to subscribe I use a cached REDIRECT link and it's fast. Create agreement call take 2 seconds, it's too long, speed is critical at checkout stage.

I use the REST API + Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express Checkout tokens (which is what REST API returns for the Billing Agreement calls) expire after 3 hours.