# Is it possible to make Paypal payment after 29 days of of capturing buyer credentials

Tags: php, paypal

My requirement is Buyer will authorize payment through credit card or express checkout via Paypal. Initially balance will not get deducted. after 29 days balance automatically deducted if he not canceled the transaction.

I have Two payment option one is Paypal express checkout and another is Paypal pro credit card processing.

Currently Instant payment using both payment options is working fine in my system. I just want to delay the payment for 30 days. Please someone help me if it is possible.

Comment: [billing agreement token lifetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739645/billing-agreement-token-lifetime/32741810)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this - [Billing plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/)

Comment: Is this similar to Paypal recurring payment?

Comment: At first glance - yes. You code it on PHP? If yes, follow this examples - [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/billing)